# How to set target cpu/hardware with armflang?

Tags: fortran, armflang

A question related to specifying target CPU with Arm Fortran Compiler ([armflang](https://developer.arm.com/products/software-development-tools/hpc/arm-fortran-compiler))?

1. How to set target CPU?
2. Is there any way for armflang to autodetect the CPUs?
3. Which CPUs does it support?

Comment: Interesting compiler, but I doubt they have `double precision` with 16 bytes and `double complex` as 8 bytes as the manual suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arm Fortran Compiler ([armflang](https://developer.arm.com/products/software-development-tools/hpc/arm-fortran-compiler)) supports -mcpu= option. When set to -mcpu=native, it tries to detect the host CPU. This enables armflang to make CPU specific optimizations as compared to generic Arm related optimizations.

The 18.4 release supports following targets

1. Cavium ThunderX2 (-mcpu=thunderx2t99)
2. Hisilicon Hi1616 (-mcpu=cortex-a72)
3. Qualcomm Falkor hardware (-mcpu=falkor)
4. Softiron (-mcpu=cortex-a57)
5. Cavium ThunderX (-mcpu=thunderx)